# How can I make filtering a Pandas Dataframe with a condition conform to PEP8?

Tags: pandas, pylint, pep8

It seems quite standard to filter a Pandas Dataframe with a condition like this

```
filter_ = (df == True)
df = df[filter_]
```

but according to PyCharm, this does not conform to PEP 8, and I get this message using Pylint

C0121: Comparison to True should be just 'expr' (singleton-comparison)

Is there a PEP 8 friendly way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that a case of the `==` operator being overloaded to change its effect? Looks like it is. If yes, then obviously the linting tools would have a hard time recognizing this and offer meaningful advice.

Personally I am not a fan of such operator overloading that change the meaning (semantics). I would avoid them, since they change the way one should read the code and are confusing or at least ambiguous.

Maybe I would recommend, either keeping the same ambiguous notation and disable the one specific linting error for that instruction:

- `filter_ = (df == True)  # pylint: disable=singleton-comparison` [[*doc*](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message)]

or using a more explicit notation (I am not familiar with *pandas*, so I do not guarantee the following code, but at least the idea should be somewhat applicable in any context, not only *pandas*):

- `filter_ = df.eq(True)` [[*doc*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)]
- `filter_ = df.bool` (really not sure about this one) [[*doc*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bool.html)]

Comment: filter_ = df.eq(True) works nicely. Here a link to the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html